# how to scroll to a list-group-item using javascript

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have a bootstrap list-group with vertical scrollbar and fixed height. The active item is selected programmatically when the group is created.

when the list is displayed, the active item is not visibile, because it's out of the range of displayed items. I would like to know how to scroll the list programmatically using javascript, so that the active item becomes visible.

```
<div class="panel-body list-group" style="height:200px; overflow-y:scroll">
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">REVOK1.1</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">REVOK1.2</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">REVOK1.4</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">REVOK1.5</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item ">REVOK1.6</a>
    <a href="#" class="list-group-item active">REVOK1.7</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is simple to achieve with [Jquery](https://jquery.com/) using the code below:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('html, body').scrollTop: $("a.active").offset().top;
});
```